# How to extract elements in nested json in python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I created a .json file that stores my dataset types and dir paths. I am able to pull the information for each dataset type, but I do not know how to attempt to pull the elements associated with the dataset.

I am currently on Python 3.5 and I am using the built-in import json

This is a sample of the code I used to write my .json file

```
#All Vid4 Dataset paths with JSON
d = {}

d ["Vid4_GT_Calendar"] ='{"dataset": "Vid4", ' \
                  '"Type": "GT", ' \
                  '"name": "Calendar", ' \
                  '"path": "C:Dataset_GT\\GroundTruth\\Vid4\\calendar" ' \
                  '}'
d ["Vid4_GT_City"] ='{"dataset": "Vid4", ' \
                  '"Type": "GT", ' \
                  '"name": "City", ' \
                  '"path": "C:Dataset_GT\\GroundTruth\\Vid4\\city" ' \
                  '}'
d ["Vid4_GT_Foliage"] ='{"dataset": "Vid4", ' \
                  '"Type": "GT", ' \
                  '"name": "Foliage", ' \
                  '"path": "C:Dataset_GT\\GroundTruth\\Vid4\\foliage" ' \
                  '}'
d ["Vid4_GT_Walk"] ='{"dataset": "Vid4", ' \
                  '"Type": "GT", ' \
                  '"name": "Walk", ' \
                  '"path": "C:Dataset_GT\\GroundTruth\\Vid4\\walk" ' \
                  '}'
```

Using the code below I am able to isolate the information to one dataset type.

```
#Reads the json
with open("datasetdir.json","r") as f:
    data= f.read()
#Decode the json file
dsjson= json.loads(data)
```

Using `print(dsjson["Vid4_GT_City"])` I am able to get the output that reads `{"dataset": "Vid4", "Type": "GT", "name": "City", "path": "C:Dataset_GT\GroundTruth\Vid4\city" }`

What should I do next if I want to extract and save the values of  "dataset", "Type", "name" and "path" as python variables.
If I attempt to do it for all items in the .json, (eg. for every "Vid4_GT_.." that is in the json, it will extract and save the values as variables. ) is there a way to "loop" or replicate the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So each key has a json-decoded string, how about:

```
dsjson_city = json.loads(dsjson["Vid4_GT_City"])
print(dsjson_city["dataset"])
```

More generic:

```
for key in dsjson:
    dsjson[key] = json.loads(dsjson[key])
    print(dsjson[key]["dataset"])
```

Comment: Thank you! this solved the issue i had with the nested json!